# selenium python stuck on this line

Tags: python, xpath, selenium

Why does my code:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'%s')]]" % ('Sorry'))
```

Get stuck and won't pass this line? Even if I do something like:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'%s')]]" % ('Sorry'))
```

Complete code:

```
# gets stuck here
if self.is_text_present('Hello'):
    print 'Hello'

# rest of code

def is_text_present(self, text):
    try:
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "%s")]' % (text))
    except NoSuchElementException, e:
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: Could you provide the page source you're performing this on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath can be simplified to

```
"//*[contains(text(),'%s')]" % ('Sorry')
```

Perhaps try something like:

```
import contextlib
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui

with contextlib.closing(webdriver.Firefox()) as driver:
    ...
    # Set up a WebDriverWait instance that will poll for up to 10 seconds
    wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    # wait.until returns the value of the callback
    elt = wait.until(
        lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//*[contains(text(),'%s')]" % ('Sorry')
            ))
```

From [the docs](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html):

> This waits up to 10 seconds before throwing a TimeoutException or if
>   it finds the element will return it in 0 - 10 seconds.

---

To debug the problem you might try saving the HTML source to a file right before calling `find_element_by_xpath` so you can see what the driver is seeing. Is the XPath valid for that HTML?.

```
def is_text_present(self, text):
    with open('/tmp/debug.html', 'w') as f:
        time.sleep(5)  # crude, but perhaps effective enough for debugging here. 
        f.write(driver.page_source)
    try:
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "%s")]' % (text))
    except NoSuchElementException, e:
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: what is ui in your ui.WebDriverWait?

Comment: I got this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "users.py", line 49, in test_add_user
    wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath('/*[contains(text(), "%s")]' % ('Hello')))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 55, in until
    raise TimeoutException()
TimeoutException: Message: None

Comment: Either the timeout duration of 10 seconds was not long enough, or else `Hello` does not show up in the text of any element. Perhaps try inspecting `driver.page_source` to make sure the HTML contains `Hello`. If it does, it may help posting a snippet of the HTML, or even better, the url so we could try running code.

Comment: I have edited the original question so you can see my function better. Unfortunately the website is in my VM and you can't access it

Comment: Perhaps save and inspect the HTML source right before calling `find_element_by_xpath`. Could the server be returning some other result every so often?